# Javascript, cloning page elements

Tags: javascript, html

In my web-app, I need to create a number of identical blocks with different contents. I don't want to form the elements fully on the server, taking into account that some of these elements will need to be created from the user's input. Thus i see two ways of creating such blocks on the client side:

1. Using jQuery (or just javascript) create the block element by element. The drawbacks is that the piece of code that creates those blocks is not recognisable HTML, which is bad in my opinion, and it is also hard to modify.
2. Create an HTML element (say, a div), make it invisible and then clone it and use it to create the necessary new elements.

Still, i am not sure which of the ways is better, and probably there might be a better variant. I tried to google this issue, but couldn't find anything.

What would you recommend?

Comment: @lbolit sorry stack doesn't allows me to reply you on comment, i would say just, YES ... for replying you

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for javascript templates? There are many implementations. Here is one [overview](http://blog.reybango.com/2010/07/09/not-using-jquery-javascript-templates-youre-really-missing-out/).

Answer (score 3):

jquery

```
var elementClone  = $(element).clone();
```

or (not better):

```
var elementClone = $(element).html();
```

javascript

```
var elementClone = document.getElementById('elementID').cloneNode(true);
```

hope this help you

Comment: Yes, i know _how_ to clone an element, i am just not sure if this is the way to go. From your reply i gather, that it is?

Answer (score 1):

You could always use basic DOM

```
var clone = document.getElementById('elementID').cloneNode(true);
document.body.appendChild(clone); //wherever you want to place the cloned element
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to use a template engine, such as [mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js), [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template) or [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to give very good answer to your question without more details on "*identical blocks*" and "*different contents*" structure.

I was resolving similar (or rather it sound similar) problem some time ago and [Pure template engine](http://beebole.com/pure/documentation/tutorials/) ([repeat a node example](http://beebole.com/pure_git/tutorial/tuto5.html)) was very good to solve my issue.

Comment: Basically, it is a block containing a title (different in each case), text, rating, date and some buttons to allow users to do things with these blocks (like editing, deleting, etc.).

Comment: It would be quite easy to build your blocks with Pure. I would recommend to spend just a few minutes going through Pure tutorial and examples. That should give you good idea if it is right tool for you. And if it is then implementation would not take long.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, there are several ways to do this. The most common is to use a [templating engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_%28web%29). A templating engine allows you to focus on marking up the content, (which differs between blocks), and automates the task of outputting the surrounding markup.

A very simple example of this approach (though probably one of the least convenient) would be to markup your content as stripped down XML, and to use XSLT to transform this to your desired HTML. A tutorial on this approach can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Transforming_XML_with_XSLT

Without recommending a single templating engine, here is an article that compares various browser side alternatives: [Browser-side Template Engines Roundup: Google Closure Templates, jTemplates and PURE](http://blog.pandaform.com/techie/browser-side-template-engines-roundup/)

Comment: I thought of using XML, but that would mean that i would have to use XML + XSLT for the whole page, but i use a different templating technique.

Comment: @Ibolit I know, I was just using that as an example to demonstrate how template processing works. There are much more convenient alternatives to raw XML+XSLT available now.